# Is there an integration rule to evaluate F(x)/F’(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a way of writing the antiderivative:

$$\int{\frac{F(x)}{F’(x)}dx}$$

In terms of F(x) and its derivatives / antiderivatives ? And if not, is there a proof for its non existence?

Thanks

Comment: any further restrictions on F?

Comment: Not in general. The best you can hope to do in general is to use integration by parts.

Comment: I doubt it, to be honest. I mean if you plug in some example functions there is no obvious pattern at least